# How do I automatically create custom calendar alerts for all new events

Tags: calendar

The Mac OS Calendar allows for all kinds of custom alerts, once an entry has been scheduled.  However, Calendar preferences allows only a limited set of times and no custom alerts, as default, and only one alert at that.  I find the normal calendar alerts far too easy to miss and want all my events to really get my attention.  How do I apply a custom alert to go off at the precise time(s) of my choosing for all calendar entries added to my calendar?